# Flutter and Android Studio Maximum Heap Size Problem

Tags: android, flutter, heap-memory

I am attempting to learn how to build a Flutter application.  I am using Android Studio for the IDE and while I'm developing I get the message Low Heap Warning ...,

If I load the project and look is Help>Change Memory Settings the dialog tells me the current value is 1280 MB and if I change is and save, once restarted this always reads the same result, 1280 MB.

If instead, I look in File>Settings > ... > Memory Settings the current value is 3072 MB.

and if I look in studio64.vmoptions it shows the 3072m.

Is there a reason I keep running low on Heap?

Comment: can you tell me what is your Ram size in the system.

Comment: please follow this link https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

Comment: This computer has 16GB of ram, it is linux on an intel i7-5820K cpu.

Comment: I thought I wrote this in the question but, in studio64.vmoptions the line is  -Xmx3072m